# MIDI file player like aplaymidi on Linux (MIDI output, no audio), with more interactive features

Tags: linux, midi

I'm looking for an application on Linux who can read MIDI files and play them to a MIDI channel (ALSA or JACK).

`aplaymidi` does this well, but I need additional features:

- Hot reloading when the file has been updated;
- Interactive features: view the clock in live, be able to move on the timeline.

A text-based application would be preferred.

Is there a program which can do this?

Comment: I'm sure you've heard about Timidity (and maybe `timidity -iA`. I kind of like to use vanBasco's Karaoke Player via wine, sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find some program which did fit all my needs, so I wrote a CLI player  to remedy this, which has these features:

- hot reload, even when playing;
- can move forward and backward;
- can restrict the play zone precisely, in order to work on a part of the score;
- loop mode;
- auto-return mode (go back to where the play started after pausing).

Here is the repo, for those who are interested: https://gitlab.com/yolenoyer/midiplay (Rust toolchain is needed for compiling).

[image: midiplay screenshot]